# Launching .apk from Code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

```
Intent install_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
install_intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
      .getExternalStorageDirectory() 
          + "app-release.apk")),
          "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(install_intent);
```

So, I am creating an application that checks for updates on launch. it downloads a file from a location, and then launches this intent to run the .apk. Unfortunately, when I do it, it gives me the error "there is a problem parsing the package android studio".

If I navigate to the download path, and run the .apk manually, it works just fine to install.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
File apkFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                  .getAbsolutePath() + "/app-release.apk");
Intent install_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
install_intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), 
     "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(install_intent);
```

Comment: Awesome. Didn't realize that splitting it up would fix the issue. Thanks.